# Is there a good solution for persist state with version infomation(because of different released app may have some changes in state object)

Tags: c#, version, state, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I want to persist the state of the project to disk and restore the state  when I reopen the project next time.

eg. there is a `ViewState` class for state

```
//Version 1:
class ViewState
{
 public string ID{get;set;}
 public string CheckedSomeState{get;set;}
 public string ToRemoved{get;set;}// will removed in version2
 public string ToRenamed{get;set;}// will renamed in version2
}

//Version 2:
class ViewState
{
 public string ID{get;set;}
 public string CheckedSomeState{get;set;}
 public string NewStateVersion2{get;set;}//new in version2
 public string ToRenamedNewNameVersion2{get;set;}
}

//Version 3:
...
```

Question:
I want to serailize the `ViewState` into xml file using XML serializer.
back compatibility when 'ViewState' was changed.(APP version 2 can open file was genereated by App version 1 )

I have a Idea:
To use some attributes for the 'ViewState' porject to mark the changes in the new version if there are some changes . and custome xml serializer to persist the 'ViewState'.
such as:

```
//Version 2:
class ViewState
{
 public string ID{get;set;}
 public string CheckedSomeState{get;set;}

 [New]
 public string NewStateVersion2{get;set;}

 //[Removed]
 //public string ToRemoved{get;set;}

 [Rename(OldName="ToRenamed",NewName="ToRenamedNewNameVersion2")]
 public string ToRenamedNewNameVersion2{get;set;}
}
```

**Is there another good solution for the scenario ?**

Comment: I don't think persisting setting to the disk is a good idea for a website because it does not scale very well.  I would look at using asp.net profile for saving settings.

Comment: @KenTucker I persist the state for the Winform client not for the website .I want to save some states of the views in Winform. sucn as  save the winform's dockpanel state...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary or list of attributes as well and add XML serialization attributes for example:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;    

[XmlRootAttribute("ViewState")]
class ViewState
{
   [XmlAttribute("ID")
   public string ID { get; set; }

   [XmlArray("Attributes")]
   [XmlArrayItem("Attribute")]
   public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

[XmlRootAttribute("Attribute")]
class Attribute
{
   [XmlAttribute("Key")]
   public string Key { get; set; }

   [XmlAttribute("Value")]
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then you have an easy access to all your state attributes.

Comment: I don't think the solution can resolve the back compatibility.when I rename the property .the old state object can't be deserialized by `XMLSerializer`,because of the oject's class have changed and  can't find the correlated type by `XMLSerializer`.(In fact in my idea I will use custom serializer)